# Is there a command for cron job to run after every 14th of a month which should be a saturday(first Saturday after 14th or third Saturday of month)

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task, crontrigger

Is there a command for the cron job to run after every 14th of a month which should be a Saturday(only on the first Saturday after 14th or the third Saturday of the month) at 11.59 pm

I need to know the command of the cron job

59 23 * * 6 [ "$(date +%d -d tomorrow)" -gt 14 ] && [ "$(date +%u -d tomorrow)" -eq 6 ] && the task

I have used the above expression. but still unsure if any other expression can do the same job more efficiently.

Comment: if today is saturday (`59 23 * * 6`) how can tomorrow also be saturday?

Comment: your question is ambiguous: `run after every 14th` could  mean every day following 14th (as your `-gt 14` implies) or "after the 14th has ended" (as your `59 23` implies. To clarify, please edit your question to add examples of dates when cron should / shouldn't run.

Comment: Do you mean "the **first** Saturday after the 14th" or "**every** Saturday after the 14th"?

Comment: @jhnc My bad..After the 14th has ended is the  correct phrase

Comment: @glennjackman it is the first saturday after 14th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: @jhnc found that the spec (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) indicates that while there is a lot of "ANDing", sometimes there is "ORing": "Finally, if either the month or day of month is specified as an element or list, and the day of week is also specified as an element or list, then any day matching either the month and day of month, or the day of week, shall be matched."

Based on that, I think your original approach is probably the right one.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

`cron` fields are "anded" together, and ranges are permitted, so this should work:

```
59 23 14-31 * 6 <the task>
```

Comment: depending on the cron, this will probably run on (H:M) AND ((dom in 14-31) OR (dow = 6))

Comment: Any idea on which `cron`s OR and which AND?

Comment: cron is not portable. interpretation of fields (beyond the very simple and basic) is implementation-dependent. OR: ([some linux](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), [freebsd](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE+and+Ports); AND: [sunos](https://www.unix.com/man-page/sunos/1/crontab/), [hpux](https://www.unix.com/man-page/hpux/1/crontab/); unspecified: [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/crontab-1.html), [plan9](https://plan9.io/magic/man2html/8/cron),

Comment: `some linux` - any ideas which?

Comment: the ones using an implementation based on vixie cron?

Comment: I'm wrong. there is a standard (which mandates OR): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html

Comment: Good find. That's unfortunate. Looks like the originally posted question contains the closest thing to the best way (assuming the logic in the check is correct).

Answer (score 0):

The first Saturday after the 14th is somewhere in the range 15 to 21:

```
01 00 * * 6 d=$(date '+%-d'); [ "$d" -ge 15 ] && [ "$d" -le 21 ] && the task
```

The hyphen in `%-d` is intended to remove the zero-padding from the day so `08` and `09` are not interpreted as invalid octal numbers. Check your `date` man page.

I'm confused why you're launching the cron entry at 23:59 and checking tomorrow, so I launched at 00:01 and checked today.

The cron entry is already constrained by day 6, so I'm not double checking that with date.